# Using Material Tailwind and Tailwind css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using tailwind for my React Project and decided to use Material Tailwind library for some components. The problem is, using Material Tailwind require you to wrap you tailwind.config.js file with "withMT()" like this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-tailwind/react):

```
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");

module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});
```

But when I do that, some of the tailwind styling properties including some colors like slate, amber, cyan etc. stops working and it destroys my previous stylings.
Is there a way to use material tailwind without losing any tailwind features?

I tried using removing the `withMT()` that I wrapped my tailwind.config in, but then some of the Material Tailwind styles wont work.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this =>

```
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";
import withMT from "@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["var(--font-manrope)"],
      },
      fontWeight: {
        regular: "400",
        medium: "500",
        "semi-bold": "600",
        bold: "700",
      },
      colors: {
        // Absolute Colors
        white: "#FFFFFF",
        black: "#000000",
      },
    },
  },
  darkMode: "class",
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/forms")],
};
const withMaterialTailwind = withMT(config);

export default withMaterialTailwind;
```